# ImportError: No module named oauth_dance

Tags: python, eclipse, twitter, pydev

I am using PyDev and Eclipse to create a project that uses Twitter Search API to collect data. When I try to run it I get the error saying

```
from twitter.oauth_dance import parse_oauth_tokens
ImportError: No module named oauth_dance
```

I have already installed twitter using `pip install twitter`, there is a module called oauth_dance.py and oauth_dance.pyc in the twitter folder in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages which is in PYTHONPATH. I already tried uninstalling and then installing twitter again, restarted Eclipse and it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: If oauth_dance is in site-packages directly, just import oauth_dance leaving off the twitter.

Comment: It's in folder twitter in site-packages... I tried it both ways, it still says there is no module named oauth_dance

Comment: See if you can import it outside of eclipse.  If you can then its an Eclipse configuration issue. I just installed twitter and imported twitter.oauth_dance in IPythonQTC. Suggest checking what is PYTHONPATH in Eclipse.  Instructions for this are in http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html.

Comment: I tried to run the same code in PyCharm and it gives me the same error. And in Eclipse I checked PYTHONPATH and it has site-packages there and everything the link says there should be

Comment: If PyCharm gives the same error, its not due to Eclipse and there is something about your Python configuration that is not what its supposed to be. I went through the whole process of installing and configuring PyDev 4.3.0.201508182223  with Python 2.7.10 in the J2EE edition of Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) running Java version "1.7.0_55" on  64-bit Windows 7. Then I created a Python project with a package in it and a module in that and in the module was able to import and use twitter.oauth_dance with no problem.

Comment: Hmmm, this is the first time I am working in Python so I don't know what to do now... I installed everything according to instructions on official web page, and I have everything it says I should in my Path. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Where did you get your Python distribution and what version is it?  It looks like that is where the problem is. A few weeks ago I worked with a Twitter API called tweepy and could not get it to work with Python 3.4.3 due to a Stream IO issue. I have had a great experience using Continuum Analytics Python distributions and am running Python 2.7.10 as the base version and 3.4.3 in an env (environment). Its available from http://continuum.io/.

Comment: I got Python 2.7.10 here(https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) for 64 bit Windows 8 and just downloaded twitter package using command prompt and `pip install twitter`